# Partial Matches in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

having some issues finding partial matches using three different ranges for my list. Please see the attached photo for more details. I've tried Regexmatch, If Search, If Find, If Match, Vlookup. The results I would like to get are on columns B, C, D according to the three different searches we conduct based on columns I, K, M for the linked photo included below.
[Screen Shot of Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V25ON.png)

Here is an example Spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cET5QItNTP_hueVczzXR-1zFqV1xi5preMa0f2xoD3M/edit#gid=1978015687

For instance, I feel that this formula is close to working, but could not quite get it.

=IF(MATCH(D8, J:J), 1, 0)

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can provide.

Comment: Please share a sheet with toy data and edit permissions. Describe at least one of 1s - what was found and where exactly?

Comment: Could you share a copy of the spreadsheet with the formulas you tried? Also, on the formula you posted why are you using column L if on the sheet is empty?

Comment: Here is the example as a spreadsheet (also edited into the original post). There is a better explanation of our problem as well as descriptions of the results we are looking to return. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cET5QItNTP_hueVczzXR-1zFqV1xi5preMa0f2xoD3M/edit#gid=1978015687
(Column L was a typo) @Kessy 
Thanks for your help, let me know if I can provide any other information.

Comment: Here is the example as a spreadsheet (also edited into the original post). There is a better explanation of our problem as well as descriptions of the results we are looking to return. docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/… @kishkin Thanks for your help, let me know if I can provide any other information.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Is your picture present the accurate result which you want same from the attached sheet. Col `C` `D` `E`. and can you open the `Edit` access to sheet. @Zigzagzot

Comment: It is available to be edited now. Within the spreadsheet, C3:E19 are the desired results. I am having issues creating a formula that balances Type I and II errors. @Hafiz

Comment: I have made some changes in the above linked sheet please see and let me know is it working fine

Comment: So what you want is for each cell on column G, check if it is similar to the values on column  J -> Formula 1 / column L -> Formula 2 and column N -> formula 3 right? Or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 0):

The formula with most accuracy that can cover you use-cases is below. I added a new sheet in your G-Sheet called "Gangula - SO Example" with the solution implemented in cells with Green border.

```
=IF(OR(ArrayFormula(IFerror(IF($K$27:$K$39="",0,SEARCH($K$27:$K$39,$H27)),0))),1,0)
```

This solves more than 90% of the tests that you have added in the Google Sheet.

Sample Screenshot:
[image: Sample Screenshot of the solution]

Comment: I stored the sheet in my drive for testing and backup: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VgU61eCUjAHRk4u6HXIEICfHvTOrLxGqLpd4naLH3VY/edit?usp=sharing